# Update Three.js Raycaster After CSS Tranformation

Tags: javascript, css, three.js

I am trying my hands on WebGL using Three.js. I am a beginner and I decided to try out something similar to [this](https://unfiltered.news). I have been able to achieve most of it. The issue I am currently facing is updating the raycaster and object after moving the canvas left. Whenever I hover after the canvas has been moved, it doesn't reflect on the sphere except I move the mouse eastwards, some distance away from the sphere. I have checked out several posts, I tried moving the camera and sphere position to no avail.

Here's the code:

```js
let scene, camera, renderer;
var raycaster, mouse, INTERSECTED;
let SCREEN_WIDTH = window.innerWidth
let SCREEN_HEIGHT = window.innerHeight
let canvas = document.getElementById('scene')
let objects = []

init();
animate();

$(".hamburger").on("click", function () {
  $(".hamburger").toggleClass("active");
  $("#scene").toggleClass("slide-left");;
});

function init() {
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    canvas: canvas,
    antialias: true
  });
  renderer.setSize(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
  renderer.setClearColor(0x000000);
  
  scene = new THREE.Scene();
  
  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
    100, SCREEN_WIDTH / SCREEN_HEIGHT, .1, 10000);
  camera.position.set(0, 0, 10);
  camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));
  
  var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(5, 32, 32);
  var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );
  sphere = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  objects.push(sphere)
  scene.add(sphere);
  
  raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
  mouse = new THREE.Vector2();
  
  document.addEventListener('mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false);
  document.addEventListener('mousemove', onHover, false);
  document.addEventListener('click', onClick, false);
  window.addEventListener('resize', render, false);
  
  scene.add(new THREE.AmbientLight(0x333333));
  var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 0.8);
  light.position.set(50, 3, 5);
  scene.add(light);
}

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  render();
}
function onDocumentMouseMove(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  mouse.x = (event.clientX  / SCREEN_WIDTH) * 2 - 1;
  mouse.y = - (event.clientY / SCREEN_HEIGHT) * 2 + 1;
}

function onClick() {
  raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);
  var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(objects);
  console.log("I was click: ", intersects)
}

function onHover() {
  raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);
  var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(objects);
  
  if (intersects.length > 0) {
    if (INTERSECTED != intersects[0].object) {
      if (INTERSECTED) INTERSECTED.remove(INTERSECTED.sphere);
      INTERSECTED = intersects[0].object//.geometry;
      
      var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(5.1, 32, 32);
      var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        color: 0xff5521,
        opacity: 0.01
      });
      sphere1 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
      INTERSECTED.sphere = sphere1
      INTERSECTED.add(sphere1);
    }
  } else {
    if (INTERSECTED) INTERSECTED.remove(INTERSECTED.sphere);
    INTERSECTED = null;
  }
}

function render() {
  sphere.rotation.x += 0.01
  camera.aspect = SCREEN_WIDTH / SCREEN_HEIGHT;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
};
```

```css
body {
   height: 100%;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
  }

  #scene {
   position: relative;
   height: 100%;
   -webkit-transition: transform .7s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: transform .7s ease-in-out;
   -ms-transition: transform .7s ease-in-out;
   -o-transition: transform .7s ease-in-out;
   transition: transform .7s ease-in-out;
  }

  .bar {
   display: block;
   height: 3px;
   width: 30px;
   background-color: #00ff00;
   margin: 5px auto;
   -webkit-transition: all .7s ease;
   -moz-transition: all .7s ease;
   -ms-transition: all .7s ease;
   -o-transition: all .7s ease;
   transition: all .7s ease;
  }

  .hamburger {
   position: fixed;
   right: 40px;
   top: 20px;
   z-index: 3;
   -webkit-transition: all .7s ease;
   -moz-transition: all .7s ease;
   -ms-transition: all .7s ease;
   -o-transition: all .7s ease;
   transition: all .7s ease;
  }

  .hamburger.active .top {
   -webkit-transform: translateY(7px) rotateZ(45deg);
   -moz-transform: translateY(7px) rotateZ(45deg);
   -ms-transform: translateY(7px) rotateZ(45deg);
   -o-transform: translateY(7px) rotateZ(45deg);
   transform: translateY(7px) rotateZ(45deg);
  }

  .hamburger.active .bottom {
   -webkit-transform: translateY(-10px) rotateZ(-45deg);
   -moz-transform: translateY(-10px) rotateZ(-45deg);
   -ms-transform: translateY(-10px) rotateZ(-45deg);
   -o-transform: translateY(-10px) rotateZ(-45deg);
   transform: translateY(-10px) rotateZ(-45deg);
  }

  .hamburger.active .middle {
   width: 0;
  }

  .slide-left {
   -webkit-transform: translateX(-250px);
   -moz-transform: translateX(-250px);
   -ms-transform: translateX(-250px);
   -o-transform: translateX(-250px);
   transform: translateX(-250px);
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/86/three.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="scene"></canvas>
<div class="hamburger">
  <div class="bar top"></div>
  <div class="bar middle"></div>
  <div class="bar bottom"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**1)** Please include the full code of your fiddle. When (not if) your fiddle goes away, so does the context of your question, and this answer.

**2)** You're attaching the mouse events to the document, not to the part that's moving. Use this instead:

```
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false);
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', onHover, false);
```

**3)** [`clientX`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/clientX)/[`clientY`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/clientY) don't behave how you're expecting them to. Use [`offsetX`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/offsetX)/[`offsetY`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/offsetY) to get the coordinates relative to the canvas (provided you followed step 2). (Don't worry that MDN says it's experimental, it works just fine in browsers that support WebGL.)

```
mouse.x = (event.offsetX / SCREEN_WIDTH) * 2 - 1;
mouse.y = - (event.offsetY / SCREEN_HEIGHT) * 2 + 1;
```

Comment: Thaks finally I make it.