# three.js mouse offset with raycasting and intersecting

Tags: javascript, three.js, mouseevent, raycasting

I've just started graphics programming with Three.js and I am trying to get a mouseover interaction with some shapes for a project I am working on. I have tried some of the other answers from similar questions but I still cannot get the mouse to interact with the cube in my code.

I am trying to use other GUI elements on the page so I cannot have just a 3D view on a single page.

This is the example I am trying to follow from jsfiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/cn7ecoaa/

I have changed the mousedown to mousemove which works perfectly however the problem occurs when I put the container into another div instead of putting it into the document body.

This is the layout of the page

[image]

There is an intersection when my mouse is not over the cube, but just below View 1 as you can see.

I know the solution is to change the offset for mouse.x and mouse.y but I am unable to find the correct value.

This is the html for the layout:

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div id='view1' class="well">
            <h4>View 1</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div id="view2" class="well">
            <h4>View 2</h4>
            <div id="canvas"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
container = document.getElementById( 'canvas' );
view2 = document.getElementById( 'view2' );
view2.appendChild(container);

CANVAS_WIDTH = 400,
CANVAS_HEIGHT = 400;

renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT);
container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

scene = new THREE.Scene();

camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, CANVAS_WIDTH / CANVAS_HEIGHT, 1, 1000);
camera.position.y = 150;
camera.position.z = 500;
camera.lookAt(scene.position);
scene.add(camera);


controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, container);
scene.add(new THREE.AmbientLight(0x222222));

var light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1);
camera.add(light);

mesh = new THREE.Mesh(
    new THREE.BoxGeometry( 200, 200, 200, 1, 1, 1 ),
    new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color : 0x0080ff }
    ) );
scene.add( mesh );
objects.push( mesh );

// find intersections
var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
var mouse = new THREE.Vector2();


// mouse listener
document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
    mouse.x = ( ( event.clientX - renderer.domElement.offsetLeft ) / renderer.domElement.clientWidth ) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = - ( ( event.clientY - renderer.domElement.offsetTop ) / renderer.domElement.clientHeight ) * 2 + 1;

    raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);
    intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(objects);

    if (intersects.length > 0) {
        info.innerHTML = 'INTERSECT Count: ' + ++count

    }

}, false);
```

Comment: Check out part 3 of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45535513/update-three-js-raycaster-after-css-tranformation/45537592#45537592

Comment: Thank you - I got it to work. I wasn't sure which div to use as the offset but it turned out to be the canvas left offset.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail which value solved it for you?